# I have two tables (Entity Framework). I want to count an average based on one another, but only count one record once. How to do it?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, entity-framework

I have a table with authors and one with books. They are connected in the book's `authorID`. I want to count the average of author's age, based on genre. It looks like this:

- Books: ID, Title, Genre, *authorID*
- Authors: *authorID*, Name, Age

I want to get the average of ages grouped by genre. But there are books in the database from the same author. I want to count them only once in this query. I have this, but this counts them every time again if the writer is the same:

```
var query = from books in this.bookRepository.ReadAll()
            join authors in this.authorRepository.ReadAll() on books.writerId equals authors.authorId
            select new
                   {
                       books.booktype,
                       authors.age,
                       authors.authorId,
                   };

 var result = from g in query
              group g by g.booktype into groupedTypes
              select new AverageOfWritersAgeInGenreModel
                     {
                         Genre = groupedTypes.Key,
                         Age = groupedTypes.Average(x => x.age).Value,
                     };
```

Comment: You first query give each property a name.  From : books.booktype, To : bookType = books.booktype,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there, you just have to take `Distinct` values from your select:

```
            select new
                   {
                       books.booktype,
                       authors.age,
                       authors.authorId,
                   };
```

I had rewritten the code to LINQ extensions:

```
            var authors = new List<Author>(); // for simplicity
            var books = new List<Book>(); // for simplicity

            var result = authors
                .Join(books, a => a.AuthorId, b => b.AuthorId,
                    (author, book) => new {author.AuthorId, author.Age, book.Genre})
                .Distinct() // Ged rid of duplicated authors for the same book genre
                .GroupBy(r => r.Genre)
                .Select(g => new {Genre = g.Key, Age = g.Average(x => x.Age)});
```